# How to include column names along with field in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert  the column header and corresponding field into another table .

```
Table1 :

col1    col2   col3   col4
1       2       3      4
```

output should look like this :

```
COL_A   COL_B   COL_C     COL_D    COL_E     COL_F      COL_G    COL_H 

col1    1       col2       2       col3       3         col4     4
```

I tried to apply unpivot , but unpivot gives me the column names vertically not horizontally .

Please help !!

Comment: select 'col1 ' || col1, ...etc

Comment: Hi!!. I can't hardcode the column names as i dont know what the column names would be

Comment: Also want to have column header as a separate field/column Not just appending the column name with record

Answer (score 3):

`UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93dd1/7)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1
    UNPIVOT(val FOR col IN (
                COL1
                ,COL2
                ,COL3
                ,COL4
                ))
    )
PIVOT(MAX(COl || ' ' || VAL) FOR COL IN (
             'COL1' as VAL1
            ,'COL2' as VAL2
            ,'COL3' as VAL3
            ,'COL4' as VAL4
            ))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93dd1/7/0)**:

```
|   VAL1 |   VAL2 |   VAL3 |   VAL4 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| COL1 1 | COL2 2 | COL3 3 | COL4 4 |
```

Comment: ,thanks for the answer ..is it possible to do something like this col1| 1| col2 |  2  |  col3  |  3  |  col4  |  4

Comment: @joe : That was not your original question. Editing a question after someone has answered is considered rude. Remove the edit and  accept this answer or ask another question.

Comment: I realised the output was perceived in a different way ,yes it was my mistake ,let me ask a new question ,I am marking your answer as useful